# Python | Rotate Rectangle and get new boundariy dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, math, rectangles

So we got the rectangle `A` and we rotate it around its corner by `x` degree. Now I want to know how to calculate the boundaries of the `new` rectangle.
What I mean with boundaries (blue rect):
[image]

known values are inner rectangle width/height/center/corners
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bounding rectange has dimensions:

```
New_Height = Old_Width * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + Old_Height * Abs(Cos(Fi))
New_Width = Old_Width * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + Old_Height * Abs(Sin(Fi))
```